# Asp.Net Core Generic Repository Pattern Soft Delete

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to create a `Soft Delete` action in my `Repository` but i have to do that without creating any interfaces or classes. Let me show u to my method first,

```
public void Delete(T model)
{
    if (model.GetType().GetProperty("IsDelete") == null )
    {
        T _model =  model;
        _model.GetType().GetProperty("IsDelete").SetValue(_model, true);//That's the point where i get the error
        this.Update(_model);
    }
    else
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(model);
        _dbSet.Remove(model);
    }
}
```

im getting a `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` exception.  of course i know what that means but i just could not figure it out and i dont know what to do. I'm not sure if there is a better way or not.

**Thanks for reading!**

Guys u really gotta look at to the where i get the error. I'm editing my question.

```
 public abstract class Base
    {
        protected Base()
        {
            DataGuidID = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid DataGuidID { get; set; }
        public int? CreatedUserId { get; set; } 
        public int? ModifiedUserId { get; set; } 
        public string CreatedUserType { get; set; } 
        public string ModifiedUserType { get; set; } 
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public bool? IsDelete { get; set; } //That's the property
    }
```

Every type of model class is inheriting from that `Base` class. When i create a new object, it takes null value. That is why im controlling that property as
`==null` .

Comment: Use `!= null`      .

Comment: its not making any sense, the else block always working because every data has a null value of ```IsDeleted``` property

Comment: That means there is no such property on the given type. Van you post full reproducer including type itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you check if the property `IsDelete` is null, and then you try to set the value of the property which is, obviously, null.

`if (model.GetType().GetProperty("IsDelete") == null )` should be

`if (model.GetType().GetProperty("IsDelete") != null )`

Edit:

Now we know that you want to check the value of a nullable bool, we have to take another approach.

```
// first we get the property of the model.
var property = model.GetType().GetProperty("IsDelete");

// lets assume the property exists and is a nullable bool; get the value from the property.
var propertyValue = (bool?)property.GetValue(model);

// now check if the propertyValue not has a value.
if (!propertyValue.HasValue)
{
   // set the value
   property.SetValue(model, true);
   ...
}
```

Comment: its not  making sense, else block always working when i do like that.

Comment: Are you sure `IsDelete` is public and a property at all?

Comment: yeah im sure because ```IsDelete``` comes from base class which is every class inherited from that class.

Comment: i edited my question. i hope u can understand.

Comment: Changed the answer, hope this helps.

Comment: thats a  better way to do it. thank u for your effort and will let u know soon.

Comment: i can set the value true now but when update triggers,it still goes null :( , atleast u show me the way how to set it, thank you so much.

Comment: Np mate, any time.